# OpenCV cvtColor without having to know source type

Tags: c++, opencv

is there a way of converting images in OpenCV (>=2) *without* having to know their source types? I realize there is cvtColor, however you have to specify the conversion code, which always requires me to create a respective switch-block, which is really tedious. I would be surprised if there were no helper functions for something common like that.

Thanks

Comment: How can you convert A to B without knowing what A,B are? What are you trying to achieve, actually?

Comment: how do you create the switch-block? Typically you either know the input type (then you can create a switch-block) or you don't  (then even the switch-block isn't possible)

Comment: I am building a generic class for processing camera data, which should be operating with different input, for example either RGB or greyscale, with either 16 or 8 bit. For example, if I need greyscale data (as many OpenCV functions only operate on 8 bit singlechannel data), I'd have to decide based on the number of channels and either call cvtColor or just copy data in case it is already in greyscale. Then, I have also to doublecheck if it is already 8 bit and maybe convert again. This is something I stumble upon frequently and it is tedious to take care of each case by hand.

Comment: You can create a single function to encapsulate the `switch` that takes 2 arguments: the source color space and the target color space and returns the correct code (if supported).  
For extra credit you could pass the source image too to verify #channels corresponds to the provided color space.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out, I usually do something like that. Thing is in every new project I run into this and have to code it again, or get it from old code and copy/paste. I thought maybe there is a convenience function I'm missing. But you are right in your answer of course, the data necessary to do that is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV `cv::Mat` does not store the format or color-space that the image data represents (only things related to memory storage like depth and channel count).

Thus, this information is external and must be managed by the user.
The management also means that if you want to convert to another color space you need to know and specify both the source and the target color-spaces.

Comment: wait, how do functions like imwrite and imshow then decide how to interpret the data?

Comment: They *assume* `C1` is grayscale and `C3` is `BGR`.